# position checkboxes in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I would like to display checkboxes centered on the page. Should I use a position fixed to solve my issue ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkboxes">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: viewModel.Addresses() ">
            <label for="CheckBoxOne"><input id="CheckBoxOne" type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: viewModel.ui.OptionsCheck" />
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkboxes label
{ 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.checkboxes input
{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxes label span
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thx for help

Comment: centered? vertically, horizontally, both?

Answer (score 1):

Using `margin: auto` on table may do the trick. Not sure if this is enough for you.

Take a look to this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxGEP/)

Comment: Judging by the fact that he's using `vertical-align: middle;` (albeit incorrectly) I think he also wants to vertically center it.

Answer (score 1):

put everything in a container the add some min-height and fixed width to that container.
the min-height is useful so that footer will always at botton even if there is no contents.

to alight the checkbox center just put some margin or padding

```
<div class="contents"><!-- put the checkbox div inside this div -->
    <div class="checkboxes">

.contents{
 width:400px;
 min-height:600px;
}

.checkboxes
 { 
     margin:50%;
 }
```

a jsfiddle demo
http://jsfiddle.net/yNxjq/

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way:

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {height: 100%;margin:0;}
#outer {height: 100%; width:100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;text-align:center}
#outer[id] {display: table; position: static;}

#middle {position: absolute; top: 50%;} /* for quirk explorer only*/
#middle[id] {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; position: static;}

#inner {position: relative; top: -50%} /* for quirk explorer only */
/* optional: #inner[id] {position: static;} */
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/SnwD3/

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
margin: auto;
```

on the checkbox element. Also your vertical-align doesn't anything really.

http://jsfiddle.net/CxGEP/1/
with gray background to show how padding works.